# share gif file from drawable folder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share, gif

i want to share gif file which is locate in drawable folder ,i tried many codes but didn't work .
i tried this

```
void shareGif(String resourceName){

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";

    File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);



   try {
        byte[] readData=new byte[1024*500];
        InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
        Log.e("eeeee",getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName())+"");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sharingGifFile);
       int i = fis.read(readData);

        while (i != -1) {
           fos.write(readData, 0, i);
           i = fis.read(readData);
        }

        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
       Log.e("eeeee",io.getMessage());
    }
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
}
```

and call this in onclicklistner

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name=getString(resource);
            shareGif(name);

        }
    });
```

can anyone help me please ,thank you.

Comment: No this will not work. And you get an error message. Which one?

Comment: cant attach empty file

Comment: Who is giving that error?

Comment: EMAIL AND ALSO TRY ALL OF BUT CANT HELP

Comment: Please don't shout. Write normal.

Comment: i didn't shout,its happens cause of capslock

Answer (score 0):

Change `your package name` -> your package name like this `com.example.test`. Your device must file chooser like the telegram,...

If used in the emulator you must install file chooser like Telegram, ES file explorer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.gif);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share gif file");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Comment: Try again. Work for me.